# Can any body Suggest me a set up that I can build it up to study the surface roughness of transparent polymeric fibres?

Tags: polymers

I need to study the surface of nylon-6 blank fibres with a thickness of nearly 40 micrometre, I work in optics lab with many optical components such as beam splitters, lenses, mirrors ... etc, can I build a system to study the topology of this fibre?

Comment: Probably on Physics SE you get more chance of an answer